# Find max in group by in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

This is my students table. I want to display the hostel,rollno,parent_inc of the student who has the max(parent_inc) in a hostel. When I'm trying this command -

```
select hostel, rollno, max(parent_inc) from students group by hostel;
```

Getting error -

```
column "students.rollno" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
select hostel, rollno, max(parent_inc) from students group b...
```

How to get it in correct way?

[image]

Without selecting rollno field it works fine.

Comment: You need to post test data as formatted text - **not an image**.  See [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) or better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12).

Answer (score -1):

Try the windowed version of MAX function:

```
select rollno
      , hostel
      , max(parent_inc) over(partition by hostel) max_parent_inc 
   from students;
```

**NOTE:** Not tested

Comment: OP wants the grouping though: "*rollno,parent_inc of the student who has the max(parent_inc) in a hostel*"

Comment: @belayer no it's not working as desired. it just gives the rollno, hostel, parent_inc of all the records in students table in ordered by hostel format. But I needed the max_parent_inc from each hostel.

Although I tried with array_agg function over rollno column and it returned correct output.

Comment: Glad you got it.  Looks like I misunderstood what you wanted. That is why you need to post clearly labeled sample data (as text - **no image**) and the expected output. See [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and here for making [text tables](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Or just create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12)